# Lines to polygons in QGIS yielding empty shapefile

Tags: qgis

I have a grid that was created in CAD that I converted to a shapefile and brought into QGIS. I would like to turn the lines into polygons. However, when I try to do so, it yields an empty file (no polygons). There is still the attribute table but it has null values for the geometry fields.

Any idea how I can fix this? If there is another route to making a polygon grid in QGIS I am open.

Here is the original grid shapefile

[image]

Here is what it looks like after I run Lines to Polygons.
[image]

Comment: Try Fix Geometries on the lines first, or fix geometries on the polygon output

Comment: You can use the Create Grid tool in the Vector - Creation section of Processing.  Choose the polygons option.

Comment: Judging by your Layers Panel, your line layer has no CRS defined, or the CRS is invalid (the `?` next to the layer name). That may be the cause.